# How to count the number of similar words present in a string when compared with a list of words?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

Suppose we have a list of words 
L1={ good, awesome , bad, super, toy , hill } and a
string S="this is an awesome line written by a good guy.".
when we map these two we need to find the number of similar words.
in this case its 2 (good, awesome)
please help me how to solve this in python.
PS: I am trying to create a binary response variable for a Machine Learning sub-task based on the similarity of words between the list and the string,
I new to Natural Language Processing,is there any function to do this easily?

PS:
 i tried by by first splitting the string and storing individual words in a list and then iterating it and comparing with the original list of words and increment the counter when the match is found.

Is there any direct function to do this in NLP?

Comment: In my project? @depperm

Comment: @AmireddyTharunreddy For this particular task. Have you done any research? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @Mitch i tried by by first splitting the string and storing in a list and then iterating it and comparing with the original list and increment the counter when the match is found. 
my question is  how to reduce the complexity or is these any direct function to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in L1:
    if x in S:
        print(x)
        counter += 1
```

First we iterate through each of the words in L1, then we use the `in` operator to check if each of these words is found in S. If it is, we print the word and increment the counter by one.

NB: this only checks if it is in S, regardless of how many instances.

Comment: It would help OP, if you can give one  line explanation of what you are doing and why you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from collections import Counter

words = set(['good', 'awesome', 'bad', 'super', 'toy', 'hill'])
latest = "this is an awesome line written by a good guy."
latest_counted = Counter(latest.strip().split())
common_words = words.intersection(latest_counted)
count_common = sum(latest_counted[wrd] for wrd in common_words)
print('There are %i words common (including duplicates).' % count_common)
```

Multiple matches of the same word will increase the count.